# i get this Error from FileProvider java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10079 does not have permission to url

Tags: java, android

I am trying to install APK from file but faced this error.

[LogcatError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vreSl.png)

My code permission

```
   public void installAPK(){
    File fileApkToInstall = new File(getExternalFilesDir("Download"),"Sharkee Browser.apk");
    Uri apkUri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(getApplicationContext(),"com.testme.dmclient.provider",fileApkToInstall);
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION|Intent.FLAG_GRANT_WRITE_URI_PERMISSION);
    intent.setDataAndType(apkUri,"application/vnd.android.package-archive");
    startActivity(intent);
    Log.i(TAG, String.valueOf(apkUri) +" install");
}
```

my xml

```
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<external-files-path
    name="external_files"
    path="." />
<external-cache-path name="Download" path="." 
    />
```

my manifest

```
<provider
        android:name="androidx.core.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="com.testme.dmclient.provider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
            android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
    </provider>
```

Comment: don't EVER post text as image. no one can copy that for adding fix, and no one want to re-write block of text for you

Comment: @snachmsm sorry, I have change it to code format. first time

Comment: @James44123 check this,https://github.com/lonelyenvoy/EasyCamera/issues/3

Comment: `get this Error from FileProvider java.lang.SecurityException: UID 10079 does not have permission to url`. Dont believe that it comes from `getUriFromFile()`. It will be produced later at starting the intent. Please investgate and rectify.

Comment: @snachmsm I have tried the fixes you send to me but it is still not working.